# Can bad encoding in a MySQL database break AJAX requests (scripted in PHP)?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, encoding, wamp

I've got a weird scenario going on here.

On my localhost running WAMP server (Apache, MySQL, PHP), I've created a webpage that displays a list of messages from a table in my database.

Let's say the DIV container was called: **#message-list**

This list gets displayed correctly (when the page is launched, PHP renders the whole page).
The HTML markup that PHP echoes-out works just fine.
The MySQL database lookup therefore also works! Great.

Now...

With a bit of AJAX and jQuery magic, I've created a form to add more messages on-the-fly, by sending a **POST** request to a PHP scripts that uses the *SAME* underlying code that generated the initial **#message-list** DIV.

The AJAX'ed PHP script does two things:

- add a record for the new message from the user;
- echoes the list (which should be updated with the new message now);

When the AJAX response comes back to the browser, the JavaScript side replaces the old list with the new **#message-list** content.

Now this... partially works.

What goes wrong - On one given page, it seems some of my previous posts are somehow "***corrupting***" something inside the AJAX request on the PHP side, resulting a **null** response (basically no HTML code gets generated to replace the **#message-list** DIV tag).

On some other pages though, the AJAX response works fine.

So my question is:

- **Is it possible that some String data in the Database breaks the execution of my PHP script because of some invalid character, badly encoded, or a quote / double-quote?**

I've tried using PHP's **htmlentities()** and **mysql_real_escape_string()** functions to solve this, but one of my pages still doesn't properly refreshes the list after the AJAX response is received.

Could it just be that I just need to cleanup / sanitize the existing content in my table?
If so, is there any easy script / query I can use to do this?

Thanks!

---

**EDIT #1:**

- MySQL version = 5.5.24-log
- By using **mysql_client_encoding**, this shows "**latin1**" (ah HA! That may be the issue then!)
- In PHP, using the **mysql_...** methods (such as mysql_connect, mysql_select_db, mysql_query, etc.);

Sample of database table with possible issue:
http://pastebin.com/PjLVmXEF

By the looks of it, many developers say PDO is recommended. I'll give that a shot and see if all errors vanish. Thanks a lot for your help so far everyone!

---

**EDIT #2:**

My current solution has been this:

I've used these queries to modify my database and the table with the encoding problem:

```
// SQL queries:
ALTER DATABASE timegrasp charset=utf8;
ALTER TABLE tg_messages CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Second, I noticed some characters in a specific record was not displaying correctly (an **Â** around some double-quoted sentences). So I manually backspaced and reinserted the double-quote in **MySQL Query Browser** to be sure it was completely gone.

On the PHP side, I only encode the messages on the way "in" to the database, with this:

```
$htmlConverted = htmlentities( $pMessage, ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401, "UTF-8" );
return mysql_real_escape_string( $htmlConverted );
```

And make sure I begin my MySQL connection with this:

```
mysql_set_charset("utf8", $DB_LINK);
```

Then, I can just read the String directly from the table without any decoding / conversion.

Finally, to test this - I copied the same message from the source (a Skype chat with my client) which had the special characters, pasted it in my web form, and now it works fine! :)

I'm not certain all the steps and parameters above were necessary, but this is what helped fix my issue.

It would be good to know for future reference though if any of this is bad practice or common "**dont's**" mistake when handling special characters in MySQL tables.

Comment: Please to provide a sample message that gets corrupted, including the database version of the message along with the version of the message as it's being corrupted.

Comment: Of all the things you have done, the only one that's necessary is calling `mysql_set_charset`. Converting the table to utf8 is good, it means the database will be able to handle the most common Unicode characters, but it wouldn't have fixed the problem on its own. I would remove the call to `htmlentities`: it converts some charaters into HTML entity codes which makes the database useless for searches because Á or Ä won't match A.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP `json_encode` function refuses to process strings that are invalid in UTF-8: it returns `null`. If you don't set a character encoding for the database connection it's possible that some other encoding is being used -- not UTF-8 -- and the data you pass to this function is in fact not valid UTF-8.

If you mentioned details such as which database API and which connection parameters you are using I could give further advice...

Comment: Okay will get those details in the next few minutes.

Comment: Added some more details. the database API is the mysql_... methods (such as mysql_connect, mysql_select_db, mysql_query). Is that what you meant?